# Extract 4 parts of string

Tags: vba

I have the following string:

```
21||10/04/2017||34390136||SOME TEXT
```

How can I extract, in vba, the four values divided by "||" ? (21 , 10/04/2017 , 34390136 , Some Text)

I need four string with each one of the values.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `SPLIT` command to split by the delimeter:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim MyString As String
    Dim MySplit As Variant
    Dim x As Long

    MyString = "21||10/04/2017||34390136||SOME TEXT"
    MySplit = Split(MyString, "||")

    For x = LBound(MySplit) To UBound(MySplit)
        MsgBox MySplit(x)
    Next x

End Sub
```

or as single lines:
`split("21||10/04/2017||34390136||SOME TEXT","||")(0)`
`split("21||10/04/2017||34390136||SOME TEXT","||")(1)`
`split("21||10/04/2017||34390136||SOME TEXT","||")(2)`
`split("21||10/04/2017||34390136||SOME TEXT","||")(3)`

Comment: Thanks, the "single lines" option did the trick. Didn't know about this command.